# Making Google account selector screen mandatory

Tags: authentication, amazon-cognito, google-authentication, aws-amplify

So I have implemented Google authentication by using AWS Amplify (federatedSignIn) in my React app. Apparently, I want to make the google account selector screen mandatory for the user to select an account to log in. Apparently, it works only when multiple google accounts are available to choose from, but if there is only one account, the system automatically uses it to login?

How can I enforce the selection screen with only one account?

Answer (score 0):

That is google's functionality. You cannot change how google handles their login requests.
See more: https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/federated-login